# Gerrit: Is there a way to push directly into master?

Tags: git, gerrit

I understand that Gerrit impose a code review process so that every changes has to get a verification plus a code review of score "+2"

My question: Is there a way to bypass these two requirements? We need to do this for debugging purposes

Comment: Debugging *what*? What do you need to debug where pushing directly to the master branch is necessary for debugging it?

Comment: We have a maven build that works on regular unix environment but failed on Jenkins.  The Jenkins build would pull files from git/gerrit, so for every test that I am doing, I need someone else to verify and code-review the file changes.  So I am thinking there may be a way to bypass the requirement.  This is for one specific project (not yet in full production) only and is only for this debugging session.

Comment: Can you reconfigure the Jenkins build to pull from not-master?

Comment: I also tried that path.  But somehow this path also did not work for me.  I was following the suggestions on https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger    Is this the best reference? I am new to Jenkins/Gerrit so can use some help from the community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You push changes to Gerrit executing the "git push" command like in the following example:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

The "refs/for" is the "magical branch" which tells Gerrit that you want to send a change to review.

You can bypass Gerrit (and the review process) pushing straight to the branch if you execute the "git push" command like following:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master
```

or simply:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

or considering that your local branch master tracks the remote branch master, just:

```
git push
```

But... to be able to push straight to the branch bypassing Gerrit you need to have **Push = ALLOW** permission for **refs/heads/*** reference.

Gerrit administrators can grant this permission to you. It's not mandatory but usually only users with "integrator" role have this permission set.

Comment: Actually, if you're on `master` branch, you can just do a `git push` in the same way as with any Git server - if the described permission allows you to do so.